# BCDedit showing the requested system device cannot be found, unable to get into safemode

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, safe-mode, bcdedit

I have a lenovo t430 laptop which boots shows the windows boot screen but then goes black for the login screen I suspect windows update has caused an issue and Im sure it can be resolved in safe mode but accessing safe mode is causing me a headach..

Pressing shift f8 attempts to boot to recovery but flashes a bluescreen saying something like oops something went wrong and restarts.

So I though I would try booking from the 8.1 install media this boots, when I select system recovery option it says something like you must select a windows installation to use this option.

I thought I would try putting the loader into legacyboot where the traditional f8 safe mode screen appears but to do this I need to use the BCDedit option but any BCDedit command comes up with the error below:

The boot configuration data store could not be opened. The requested system device cannot be found.

Goggling this indicated that the store us corrupt but I don't think this is true as windows wouldn't boot whatsoever but it does so the datastore must be OK.
I have assigned a letter to the 100mb system drive and rebuilt but no joy.
One thing that may need mentioning is bitlocker is enabled on the drive but the recovery using the dudk dies prompt and I can unlock and list the files from the command prompt.
Dies anyone gave any ideas how to get to safe mode or remove the video driver?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just edit BCD on hard disk when booted in external installation or recovery media.

You have to change one single parameter for default loader:

```
bcdedit /store PATH /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy
```

where PATH is path to BCD on hard disk, system partition.